# What is the nonverbal spell in Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them?

Tags: fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

In the movie, **Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them**, it is shown that after escaping from their death sentences, the four of them (Newt, Tina, Queenie, Jacob) go to visit Tina's goblin informant Gnarlack. Before entering the hidden place of the bar, Tina and Queenie perform a spell which changes their attires into beautiful dresses. Also Newt fixes his neck-tie using the same or some different spell.

Which is this nonverbal spell they performed?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear to have a name. Per the "*[original screenplay](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/29363501-fantastic-beasts-and-where-to-find-them)*" book;

> The steps appear to lead to a dead end: the doorway has been bricked up. Instead, a poster of a simpering debutante in evening dress, gazing at herself in a mirror, covers the end of the walkway.
>
> TINA and QUEENIE stand in front of this poster. They turn to each
> other and, in unison, raise their wands. As they do so, their work
> clothes transform into stunning flapper party dresses. TINA looks up
> at NEWT, somewhat embarrassed by her new attire. QUEENIE gazes at
> JACOB, a cheeky smile on her face.
>
> TINA steps towards the poster and slowly raises her hand. As she does
> so, the eyes of the debutante move upwards, following her every move.
> TINA knocks slowly on the door four times.
>
> NEWT, sensing the need for a change, hastily magics himself a small
> bow tie. JACOB looks on, jealously.

Possibly it's some sort of [transfiguration spell](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/magic/transfiguration/).